# Nested lists: get selected item of inner list?

Tags: sapui5

As part of my SAPUI5 application i have a list which can be used to navigate to detail pages for the selected item. Now for every list item there is also a choice for a "mode" which can be selected from a list aswell (=> nested list).
This is how the view looks like:

```
<List id="competitionList" items="{
    path: 'competitions>/results'
  }">
  <items>
    <CustomListItem
      type="Navigation"
      press="onPress">
      <VBox>
          <Text text="{
                        path: 'competitions>time',
                        formatter: '.getDescription'
                      }"/>
          <SelectList id="mode-select">
            <items>
              <core:Item key="full" text="Full"/>
              <core:Item key="one" text="Short"/>
            </items>
          </SelectList>
      </VBox>
    </CustomListItem>
  </items>
</List>
```

As you can see there is a `SelectList` inside the standard `List`. That `SelectList` will be filled according to some values inside the bound competition.

Now my question is: How can i determine which item got selected in the `SelectList` inside the `onPress` function for the pressed item of the parent `List`?

My `onPress` function currently looks like this:

```
onPress: function(oEvent) {
      var oItem = oEvent.getSource();
      var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
      oRouter.navTo("startlist", {
        showId: showId,
        competitionId: oItem.getBindingContext("competitions").getProperty("number")
      });
    }
```

Comment: Hi Puelo, is your model: competitions oData or JSON ? if it a JSON model , then you can bind selectedKey property of SelectList to a property in your competition model.  EG : `<SelectList id="mode-select" selectedKey='{competietion>mode}'>` .

Comment: @Rahul Yes it's JSON. Does `selectedKey` bind in both ways? Thus is it updated in the model when the user changes the selection inside the `SelectList` or do i have to keep track of it myself through the `onSelectionChange` callback?

Comment: if the user will select a value, the data will be in the json model ( say property 'mode'). However, if user doesn't select anything, 'mode' will not be stored i.e. 'mode' property wont be created in json model. So, best would be to create a property 'mode' in the model before , set it's value to empty string. This way you will always have 'mode' property in your model.

Comment: @Rahul alright thanks. I will try this